# How to display popover view on image click in list view each row

Tags: android

I need to show popoverview inside listview every image on click.it will shows the popover view only for listview last row image,how to solve?

https://github.com/lupidan/PopoverView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **getView()** method in adapter **setOnclickListener** to the imageView regardless of convertView is null or not.

Update:

Simply do this..(your approach not recycling view)

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_list_item,
                null);

   ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.yourIv);
   iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //Do what you want here..
                }
            });
return view;
}
```

Comment: i am not checking if convertview==null or not,just assigned View v= convertView; return v;